# How to extract float numbers from a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have string with an amount different currencies in it, e.g,

```
"454,54$", "Rs566.33", "discount 88,0$" etc.
```

The pattern is not consistent and I want to extract only float numbers from the string and the currency.

How I can achieve this in Ruby ?

Comment: The information you provide is not sufficient to answer the question. Different languages may use different notations. Rohit Jain's answer is perhaps correct, but I cannot be completely sure that there isn't any language that uses a symbol other than the period or comma as the decimal point. And, it is not clear whether or not you also want to deal with comma separated numbers.

Comment: Please read the whole question before penalties. I am using Ruby, see the last sentence.

Comment: I did read the whole question, and I know you are using Ruby. What difference does that make? And why are you assuming that I made penalties? Voting system here is anonymous.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this regex to match floating point numbers in the two formats you posted: -

```
(\d+[,.]\d+)
```

See [Demo on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/pGdpGfyjk3)

Comment: this would incorrectly match two floats when you present it with 192.168.1.1 => [192.168, 1.1]

Answer (score 8):

you can try this:

```
["454,54$", "Rs566.33", "discount 88,0$", "some string"].each do |str|
  # making sure the string actually contains some float
  next unless float_match = str.scan(/(\d+[.,]\d+)/).flatten.first
  # converting matched string to float
  float = float_match.tr(',', '.').to_f
  puts "#{str} => %.2f" % float
end

# => 454,54$ => 454.54
# => Rs566.33 => 566.33
# => discount 88,0$ => 88.00
```

#### [Demo on CIBox](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=how-to-extract-float-numbers-from-a-string-in-ruby.rb&run=true)

Comment: this would incorrectly match two floats when you present it with `192.168.1.1` => `[192.168, 1.1]`