# extract number with seperated point in a string ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to extract a point separated number format from a string?

for example a string like this

```rb
a = 'ProductX credit 1.000'
```

how to to get only the **1.000** from that string?

Thank you kindly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706706/how-to-extract-float-numbers-from-a-string-in-ruby, the regex `.match(/\d+.\d+/)` is probably the most reliable way, but it also depends on the concrete formatting of the strings and different languages may use different separators (in German it would be `,` instead of `.`).

Comment: What's the format of the "number" you want to extract? Is it always one digit followed by a `.` followed by three digits? How do (much) larger or smaller numbers look like? What about negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `split` by `space` in ruby

```
a = 'ProductX credit 1.000'
a.split(" ").last
```

Result

```
"1.000"
```

Comment: The OP said the string was just an example. What if the number doesn't come last?

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
a='ProductX credit 1.000'
```

Code

```
p a.rpartition(/\s/).last
```

Output

```
"1.000"
```

Comment: That extracts the last word, not necessarily _"a point separated number"_

Comment: You are right. Once you read this comment, I will delete my answer.